# Right agile method (Scrum, Kanban, etc.) to follow with strict release cadence

Tags: agile, scrum, development-process, release-management

In my organization there is a release cadence to deploy any piece of code to Production environment.
We have three environments, Dev, Test and Prod and we have deployment in every 15days and the dates are pre-defined for an year.

For Eg: For 2021 we have Prod Releases on *2021.06.15*, *2021.06.29*, *2021.07.13* ... so on.
Meaning - For any piece of code that has to be released on Prod on 2021.06.15, it has to be deployed to Dev on 2021.05.18 and to Test on 2021.06.01

> Dev (2021.05.18) -> Test (2021.06.01) -> Prod (2021.06.15)

We are currently following Scrum and in order to deploy anything to Prod we have to plan our user stories  to align with the release cadence.

Our sprints are planned this way that we have to complete a user story so that it is ready to be deployed to Dev at the end of the sprint.

Now issue is that, If we have multiple user stories that are dependent on each other and we are only able to finish one single user story in one sprint, we cannot deploy it to Dev at the end of the sprint since it is dependent on other user stories. And, if do deploy it to Dev, it will reach Production way before the other user stories. Which becomes a half baked thing for a user.
Also, if we don't deploy anything to Dev, the QA testing takes a hit and delays the project timelines.

We have to be agile but Scrum doesn't seem to be working for us. We want to move away from it but we do want an iterative development technique.

Can someone suggest a alternative approach to be efficient in this kind of release cadence?

Comment: There isn't a "Right agile method", that's the point of agility. But the problem here sounds like interdependent stories that take weeks to complete (not independent or small per e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INVEST_%28mnemonic%29), which sticking to or switching from scrum won't automatically fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not fair to say "Scrum doesn't seem to be working for us" when what you're doing isn't Scrum. The same problems that are preventing you from using Scrum effectively will continue to be a problem, regardless of which framework or methodology you choose.

The first thing to fix would be the dependencies and sizing of your stories. Although you may not be able to eliminate all dependencies, you have too many if you regularly cannot deploy a single user story at least once at some point during the Sprint. Unfortunately, without additional context about the system you're building and some of these stories, it's not possible to give concrete advice. There's plenty of information about splitting and decomposing stories, along with technical techniques to support more frequent integration and deployment.

I'd also strongly suggest looking at your deployment cadence. Having fixed dates for deployment to development, test, and production environments forces you into a waterfall set of activities. It would be more efficient to perform design, development, and test continuously rather than putting phases in there. QA testing needs to be a part of development, with hand-offs reduced.

These aren't easy changes, but if you want to see the benefits of Agile Software Development, you'll have to make them.

Comment: Yes, the strict release date is the main issue we are experiencing here. We call it "CI/CD" when it is clearly not. 
Thanks for the advise.

Comment: I have to disagree that fixed release dates are indicative of waterfall. A fixed date is a fixed date. If you aren't ready to deploy on the fixed date then don't deploy. Skip the date. Scrum, and agile more generally, isn't about the specifics of when you release. It's about flexibility in development so change isn't a major event. Release as needed. Release on a fixed schedule. Either way can be agile.

Comment: @GregBurghardt It's not the fixed release date alone, it's the fixed deploy to dev followed by a fixed deploy to test followed by a fixed deploy to prod. That implies a highly sequential dev/test/deploy cycle. "Phase-based Agile" isn't agile at all.

Comment: @GregBurghardt yeah, fixed productive release dates are not a problem and actually exactly what you get with "pure" SCRUM. But fixed release dates to QS are an impediment to actual agility, and prepending that with fixed releases to dev is just plain idiotic.

Answer (score 2):

With only two weeks between deployments to dev, test and production, you really have to tackle small stories. Being strict about this release schedule does not easily allow for larger Minimally Viable Products. For small applications, a single story should be an MVP. For medium and large applications multiple stories, up to an including entire epics, might be the MVP. The problem seems to be related to change management and configuration management.

You need the flexibility to deploy to dev, and maybe event test *without* having it proceed on to production. You also might need to introduce [feature flags (or feature toggles)](https://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html) to enable and disable new features. This might need to be configurable per application environment so you can enable the feature in dev, but keep it disabled in test and production. Later, you can enable it in dev and test, but keep it disabled in production. Practicing [trunk-based development](https://medium.com/@mattia.battiston/why-i-love-trunk-based-development-641fcf0b94a0) helps with this situation too, since any code change, visible or invisible, gets tested and deployed to production regularly. The advantage here is large changes become incremental in minute amounts, and each small amount is regression tested fully.

Fixed release dates are not anti-agile, anti-scrum, or pro-waterfall. The development team should be "agile" in the sense of development priorities. If the business wants fixed release dates, then the development team should be "agile" enough to accommodate that. If the business wants things released as they come through the pipes, then do that.

Be rigid in your process, but flexible with change in priorities. It sounds like your organization has a pretty rigid process. Some things cannot be changed, but the other things you have control over. Trunk-based development and feature flags can help you accomplish larger batches of work all the while ensuring regressions don't occur. Your current process seems set up for that. Don't fight it. Embrace it.

Comment: +1, using feature flags was the first thing what I thought when I read the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your release schedule is simply too frequent. If you release every 15 days that means the average feature must be coded and tested in less than 15 days. A single regression bug and you would miss the release.

Now, you might be thinking "we have an automated CD pipeline and we do loads of releases a day!", but those releases are just whatever happened to be finished at that time assuming you were working on that product that day. Plus your tests will have prevented a dev "finishing" a feature unless its bug free (to your test definition)

The dev/test/prod move every 15 days suggests that your tests *aren't* automated. So stuff you developed 15 days ago is going to come back with a bug. Then you'll have less than 15 days to fix it, push it through test for a second time AND catch up on your work for the next release.

This means you can't start work on the next release until the current release is in Prod, which means the developers are still on their hands (or at least you can't plan on their time) for the final X days it takes to regression test.

If you really want to guarantee a date for the release of feature X. Feature X has to be finished before you announce the date.